# engaging the right-click on google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to enable the rightclick function on a google map for a visible polygon.  I need the right-click option so I can enable a delete vertices after placing the polygon on the map.  However, I cannot get the addListener to recognize the right-click event.

```
function initMap() {
    var selectedShape;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {
            lat: -34.397,
            lng: 150.644
        },
        zoom: 8
    });

    var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.POLYGON,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
            drawingModes: ['circle', 'polygon', 'rectangle']
        },
        polygonOptions: {
            editable: true,
            draggable: true
        },
        circleOptions: {
            editable: true,
            draggable: true
        },
        rectangleOptions: {
            editable: true,
            draggable: true
        }


    });
    drawingManager.setMap(map);

    //load preset data


    function setJSON(Shape) {
        console.log(Shape.type);
        if (Shape.type === "circle") {
            return '{"type":"'+Shape.type +'", "lat":"'+Shape.getCenter().lat()+'", "lng":"'+Shape.getCenter().lng()+'", "radius":"'+Shape.getRadius()+'"  }';
        }
        if (Shape.type === "rectangle"){
            return '{"type":"' + Shape.type + ', "start":"'+ Shape.getBounds().getNorthEast() +'", "end":"'+ Shape.getBounds().getSouthWest() +'"}';
        }
        if (Shape.type === "polygon"){
            //eturn '{"type":"'+ Shape.type +'"}' + Shape.getPaths();
            vertice = Shape.getPath();
            console.log("vertice count:  " +  vertice.getLength());
            JSON = '{"type":"'+ Shape.type +'", "coordinates": "';
            vertice.forEach(function(xy, i) {
                JSON = JSON + xy.lat() + ' ' + xy.lng() + ', ';
            });

            JSON = JSON.slice(0,-2) + '"}';
            return JSON;
        }

        return 0
    }



    google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function(event) {

        drawingManager.setMap(null);

        var newShape = event.overlay;
        newShape.type = event.type;
        selectedShape = newShape;
        console.log(setJSON(selectedShape));

        if (newShape.type === "circle" || newShape.type === "rectangle") {

            google.maps.event.addListener(selectedShape, 'bounds_changed', function(event){
                console.log(setJSON(selectedShape));
            });

        }

        if (newShape.type === "polygon") {

            google.maps.event.addListener(selectedShape.getPath(), 'set_at', function(event) {
                // complete functions
                console.log(setJSON(selectedShape));
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(selectedShape.getPath(), 'insert_at', function(event) {
                // complete functions
                console.log(setJSON(selectedShape));
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(selectedShape.getPath(), 'rightclick', function(event) {
                console.log('right-click');
            })

        }


    });

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(document.getElementById('btnClear'), 'click', function(event) {
        selectedShape.setMap(null);
        drawingManager.setMap(map);
    });

}
```

Comment: Any of those console.log are working?

Comment: yes.  `set-at`, `insert-at`, and `btnClear->click` all work.

Comment: https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/1437/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A [MVCArray](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MVCArray) (which is what the path returns) doesn't have a rightclick event.  The [Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon) would have one.  This code works for me:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(newShape, 'rightclick', function(event) {
  console.log('right-click');
});
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/ujyaxott/1/)